# how to output dataLayer macro in custom html tag in Google Tag Manager

Tags: macros, google-tag-manager

What I'm trying to do is output custom HTML based on values that are determined on my webpage using Google Tag Manager, but the problem is I can't get my "Custom HTML" tag in GTM to fire on my webpage.  Tag, macro, and rule are specifically referring to tags, macros, and rules in GTM. Tags are things you want GTM to output onto your webpage, rules govern when those tags are fired, and macros are essentially variables that can be used within tags and rules. I believe that

```
`dataLayer.push({'orderid': '5'});`
```

would set a macro `{{orderid}}` (which was created in GTM) to equal 5.  With the macro set I can use it in the firing rule, "`if {{orderid}} is equal to 5`", which once satisfied should fire my tag.
I've tried doing the push on my webpage as well as in the console of my browser and it's not working.  The custom HTML tag never shows up on the page.  I believe that I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how this all works, but I don't know which part I am not understanding.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to be very specific and post any relevant code, and ask a very specific question!

Comment: Hi DLeh.  How can I be more specific?  What I'm trying to do is output html using the "Custom HTML" tag in GTM.  The firing rule for the tag is "if {{orderid}}} is equal to 5".  {{orderid}} is a dataLayerVariable macro that I created in GTM.  I'm under the impression that macros are set using GTM's dataLayer global variable.  I've pushed orderid to the dataLayer with "dataLayer.push('orderid': '5') and have confirmed that the data exists in the dataLayer.  The problem is that the custom html tag is not firing.

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking. What is your question? What is your code? What language is this? I have no idea what `macros` and `tags` you are using. There is plenty more information you could provide that would help others help you.

Comment: any further details you provide, do so as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Are you familiar with Google Tag Manager? There is no code aside from `dataLayer.push({'orderid': '5'});` using javascript. Tag, macro, and rule are specifically referring to tags, macros, and rules in GTM.  Tags are things you want GTM to output onto your webpage, rules govern when those tags are fired, and macros are essentially variables that can be used within tags and rules. I believe `dataLayer.push({'orderid': '5'});` should set the macro {{orderid}} to 5, which should satisfy the rule, "if {{orderid}} is equal to 5", which should then fire the tag.  Problem is tag is not firing.

Comment: Is that specific enough?  If it is then I'll edit the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: you had not written the words "google tag manager" anywhere in the post originally.

Comment: Yes, I had thought that "tag manager" was enough, but it wasn't.  I have updated the title of the question to include it and now I'll update the post as well.

Comment: Thanks DLeh for your patience and for showing me the ropes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set an event (a reserved macro name for a dataLayer Variable that trigers tags to fire).

```
dataLayer.push({
'orderid': '5',
'event' : 'orderid_set'
});
```

And then have two conditions in your rule, {{orderid}} eq 5 and {{event}} eq orderid_set respectively.

You always need an event to fire a tag, but in most cases GTM populates the event variable automatically (on pageload, dom ready etc) or via event handler tags. If you want to fire a tag independently from pageload or clicks/submits you need a custom event.

Comment: OMG! that worked like a charm! Now why couldn't Google's documentation specify that.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should also be able use the built in events gtm.dom and gtm.start if your dataLayer value is set before the tag manager code executes, but best practice seems to be to always include an event name and use that, [as Simo Ahava details here](http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/add-the-event-key-to-datalayer-pushes/)